# Fail when run Monkeyrunner

Tags: java, android, jython, monkeyrunner

Let me specify my question.

1. I installed Jython, PyDev, configure Jython interpreter in Eclipse.
2. Created a PyDev project with PyDev Module, and copypaste source code from http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkeyrunner_concepts.html (of course I changed package, activity and apk according to my project )
3. Then I run it as "Jython Run" and even "Jython unit test"

But nothing happens, except errors in Eclipse console:

```
File "G:\workspace\Test\test.py", line 3, in <module>
device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()
at com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection(MonkeyRunner.java:75)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)


java.lang.NullPointerException: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Tell me, please, what I do wrong?

Comment: Could you add some of your code to help find out where the problem is?

Comment: or try [AndroidViewClient](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki) which is 100% python